# Cucumber steps undefined

Tags: jvm, cucumber

All test steps are red in colour and error is:Steps undefined.
I have not written cucumber option now in runner class
Can some one how to write cucumber options

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: I would use your IDE to generate these using a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined steps means that they can't be found. The reasons steps can't be found is because they are not in your classpath.

I would like to suggest that you clone https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton and run it using Maven.

This will give you something that works. Transforming it into your own code is probably easier with a working solution compared to a non working solution.